# Java + Angular2 = Two projects deployed as one. How?

Tags: java, node.js, angular, frontend, backend

Recently I asked here about is it a good practice to init npm and install node_modules inside webapp package inside Java Project because I wanted to use Jeyrsey RESTful API framework as backend and Angular2 for frontend. I haven't any idea how to join that so I realized that installing ANgular2 by using npm inside webapp package would work - and it works.

But... my project structure looks like:

```
PROJECT
--src
  --main
    --Java <-- all Jersey API staff etc.
    --webapp <-- all frontend staff with Angular2
      --node_modules
      --bower_components
      --index.html
      --...
```

I got two answers and two said the same - a better option is to create two separate projects: one for frontend and second for backend. Okay - that sounds interesting but how to exactly run them together, join the requests etc? For Java I use jetty, for frontend I could use node.js, what now? Which technology should I use to join these two projects working on two different ports.

Am I somewhere wrong? Could you give me the best technologies, some advices. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would create one war-file and deploy it to the jetty. You already have a real fast web-server, you should not make things more complicated, by creating the need of a reverse proxy or CORS-header.
2. Another way would be, starting two server jetty and node.js, start a reverse proxy, which could map your backend to the one and your frontend to the other server.
3. The third would be adding CORS header. In this case your frontend would run at one port and the backend an another.

I would use the first way. It may be a good approach to use a [maven buildplugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin), which will start your frontend build with grunt. In this case you can build everything with one build-chain in one single project. The deployment would be easy (one single war-file).